# How to configure cache on IIS 10?

Tags: iis

I have a website and I have enabled caching as follows :

- Cache enabled for the server
- Cache enabled for the website I'm testing
- In the response headers, I'm setting the web content expiration after 30 days for the whole website (there is no setting for any specific folder)
- Cache is enabled for the files .css, .js, .png, .woff2
- Website browsing in incognito mode in Chrome

Screenshots :

[image]
[image]
[image]

**When I browse my website, the first time it should load all the files, but if I refresh the page, files should be loaded from cache which is not the case (screenshot below). And in the response headers of the files I have :**

- cache-control: no-cache,max-age=2592000
- content-encoding: gzip content-length: 30116 content-type:
- application/javascript date: Sun, 08 Mar 2020 04:31:20 GMT etag:
- "80b55a25ef1d51:0" last-modified: Tue, 03 Mar 2020 13:21:23 GMT
- server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0 status: 200 vary: Accept-Encoding

Does anyone know how to solve that please ?

thanks
Cheers,

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you have enabled both `clientcache` and server side output caching at the same time. Based on your description, only client-side cache is required in this case.

So please remove output caching rule from your IIS configuration.

We just have to set `<clientcache>` section

```xml
<staticContent>
    <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="1.00:00:00" />
</staticContent>
```

[image: Cache-Control: max-age=86400]

Besides, please ensure your web browser has enabled client caching. Otherwise, static files will never be cached.

Of course, failed request tracing will tell us how the cache control header generated.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Comment: Here is a link to the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/staticcontent/clientcache

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but this is my solution to this problem.

You can do this using rewrite rules. First, you'll need the module that supports IIS 10: https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Create a blank Outbound rule and give it a name such as "Cacheable Files".

Create a new Precondition and name it (such as "IsCacheableFile"). Use Regular Expressions and use "{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" for the conditioned input with a regex of the mime types you want to customize the caching for.
[image]

Set the matching scope to "Server Variable" with variable "RESPONSE_CACHE_CONTROL" and match pattern ".*".

For the action, set the type to "Rewrite" and enter the cache value you want to implement, for example "max-age=3600". Enable the "Replace existing server variable value" checkbox.

[image]

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

**Note:** You will have to force a refresh if the file is currently being cached.